# Lubuntu 19.04 Calamares Installation does not provide full disk encryption

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, whole-drive-encryption

Is it possible to install Lubuntu with the [Ubiquity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) installer used by Ubuntu?

I can't setup full disk encryption correctly with the [Calamares](https://calamares.io/) installer of Lubuntu 19.04; it has no option to use the entire disk and setup LVM encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to make the Ubiquity installer work with Lubuntu, I'd suggest manually encrypting the entire drive after completing the normal installation of Lubuntu. The Ubuntu [Community forum has a detailed how-to article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption) with support for LUKS, LVM, encrypted Boot, and manual partitioning, among other features.

[This feature request](https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/970) indicates the Calmares installer used by Lubuntu does not yet have full disk encryption.

Comment: i switched to kubuntu instead of thanks

Comment: mybe misunderstanding. why shoud lubuntu not provide fde. you mean because bootloader?

Comment: This has nothing to do wiht the bootloader.  The Lubuntu installer does not offer FDE (Full Dark Earth? Oh, Full Disk Encryption) in its installation process. It uses the new Calamares installer app (which does not have that option) instead of the Ubiquity app used by Ubuntu. If you want, you can track progress towards adding that at https://github.com/calamares/calamares/issues/970

Comment: are all calamares affected? there is an option on it to encrypt partition. wat is the diffirent. . have steps to encrypt entire drive after install. i didnt found guid for it

Comment: mey friend i found a solution. testing on it right now. i downloaded Ubuntu mini Iso 64Mb. during inatallation through internet it shows a list of all ubuntu versions to select wich one u want. i selected lubuntu. i think so we have bypassed calamers?